# generating a vector that contains larger than and less than values

Tags: r, vector

I'm currently working on a question that is as follows:

**Given that `sample <- rexp(100, rate = 1.5)` , the median of the sample is generally smaller than the mean. 
Generate a vector, `between_median_mean` , that contains all values of sample that are larger than (or equal to) the median of sample , and less than (or equal to) the mean of sample.**

my answer is: `between_median_mean <- c((sample>=median(sample)&mean(sample)<=sample))`

However, I'm only getting true/false, instead of generating values as the question asks. I would appreciate if any one can give some pointers on what I have done wrong/missing!

Edit: the output I'm getting is: `[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE` for example.

Comment: You have given R the logic it needs to label whether you would keep the observation or not. Now, you need to use that variable as a subsetting filter, so that you get back the observations which returned as true: You can subset(sample, between_mean_median) ` to grab the values you want. You were just not quite finished yet...you have the boolean logic (or mask) and you need to apply it to the data to extract what you want!

Comment: @sconfluentus thanks for your input, however I'm still a little confused. Am I correct in assuming that my logic is correct, however as I'm not 'calling' the ```between_median_mean``` of the ```sample```, that's why it's only showing the true/false options?

Comment: yes...exactly, Louis applied what I said oneof two ways, the other would be to `new_data <-subset(sample, between_median_mean)` either works find and are define similarly to work with a vector in R. The one caution I would give, is that `sample` is a function in the base package of R and using it as a variable name is not particularly PC, it overwrites (temporarily) and eliminates using that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're returning the boolean vector, instead of the actual values

If you want to return the actual values, you need to use the boolean vector to filter the initial sample. This is one of the many ways you can accomplish this task:

```
sample <- rexp(100, rate = 1.5)
test_condition_res <- sample >= median(sample) & mean(sample) <= sample

#Filter sample vector to return only TRUE values from the previous condition
between_median_mean <- sample[test_condition_res]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I can also subset the ```sample``` factor within the new vector as well. Learning something new everyday!

Comment: You're welcome @aislinx! Please remember to accept the answer if this was helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

`(between_median_mean <- sample[sample >= median(sample) & sample <= mean(sample)])`

The square brackets '[]' are used for subsetting. You say, show me only the values of sample that satisfy the conditions described.

Answer (score 1):

As @sconfluentus mentions what you need to do is:

```
 between_median_mean1 <- sample[sample>=median(sample) & mean(sample)<= sample]
```

i.e. to get the relevant slice of vector you need to slice the vector via new_vector = vector[condition]. You wrote the condition which states whether it is true or not and you just need to now apply TRUE/FALSE to whether the subset should include the value or not.

Comment: Thank you! Was wondering if it's necessary to add c() when creating vectors, or does it depend?

Comment: So c() is used when you either want to create a vector out of existing values e.g. x_vector = c(1, 2, 3) or if you want to bind existing vectors/values, e.g. x1_vector = c(x_vector, 7). Basically c stands for binding. In this case, when you pass T/F statement on a variable the result generates as a vector and there is nothing to bind as there is only one entity, so c(1)  is the same as 1.

Comment: A case where I can think c might be helpful if you switch to using which() which returns positions in vectors where the statement is true and then bind two conditions if you are using an OR statement (not in your case) and there you could pass two conditions separately and bind them together, e.g. *between_median_mean1 <- sample[c(which(sample>=median(sample)), which( mean(sample)<= sample))], so you pass the position of the vector where any of these conditions are met. But this is not your case - hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(col1 = rexp(100, rate = 1.5) %>%
             filter(between(col1, median(sample), mean(sample)))
```